# UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath"

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have set up a `UIViewController` with a table view and cell added.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *identifier = nil;
    NSString *task = [self.tasks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSRange urgentRange = [task rangeOfString:@"URGENT"];
    if (urgentRange.location == NSNotFound) {
        identifier = @"plainCell";
    } else {
        identifier = @"attentionCell";
    }
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    // Configure the cell...

    UILabel *cellLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    NSMutableAttributedString *richTask = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
                                           initWithString:task];
    NSDictionary *urgentAttributes =
    @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier" size:24],
      NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : @3.0};
    [richTask setAttributes:urgentAttributes
                      range:urgentRange];
    cellLabel.attributedText = richTask;

    return cell;
}
```

I am trying to learn storyboard and created this example code. I don't see or i am able to find that what mistake i am doing. I am stuck on this since yesterday and not abel to understand the issue.

I request your help to get me going with my learning.

It's an example that i am trying to create. The XCODE Project can be downloaded from the below url:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/72451425/Simple%20Storyboard.zip

Please look in to the code and help me move forward.

Comment: Are your 2 cell identifiers defined on cells in the storyboard?

Comment: Hi Wain, Yes i have defined two cells inside my storyboard.

Comment: Hey Wain, your help will be highly appreciated. Please as i tried to delete and create the project 10 times i am completely out with this issue.

Comment: Have you hooked up your `UIViewController` as the delegate for your `UITableView`?

Comment: Hi Yazid, I am using storyboards here so i believe i don't need to make data source and delegate connections? It's been handle by XCODE automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cell identifiers you use in your storyboard are `actionCell` and `plainCell`.

`actionCell`. Not `attentionCell`.

Use the correct cell identifier in your code

```
if (urgentRange.location == NSNotFound) {
    identifier = @"plainCell";
} else {
    identifier = @"actionCell";
}
```

Comment: Hi Matthias, Thanks a ton for the quick help. i appreciate and owe you this help!

Answer (score -3):

Your problem is here: `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];`

This can return a nil cell if no cells have been created previously. So, you need to check for it:

```
// Configure the cell...
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
if (cell == nil) {
   cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]]; //or do whatever makes sense for your new cell
}
UILabel *cellLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
NSMutableAttributedString *richTask = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:task];
NSDictionary *urgentAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier" size:24], NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : @3.0};
[richTask setAttributes:urgentAttributes range:urgentRange];
cellLabel.attributedText = richTask;
```

Comment: Since iOS 5 there is a concept called "prototype cells". If you use them correctly `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` will always return a valid cell.

Comment: The problem was with the incorrect cell names defined. But anyways thanks for the quick response my friend.